# MapView inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have a TabLayout with fragments, and one fragment contains a MapView, but every time the fragment with the MapView comes back from background, throws an error at the moment the fragment tries to create the MapView;

My Fragment looks like this:

```
public class DinerFoodMapFragment extends Fragment {

    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap map;

    public DinerFoodMapFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diner_food_map, container, false);
        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                map = mMap;
                CameraUpdate center =
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(25.6714,
                                -100.309));
                CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

                map.moveCamera(center);
                map.animateCamera(zoom);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }
}
```

And crashes on this line `mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

This is the error:

```
05-30 14:53:27.725 20916-20916/com.frevo.frevo E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState
                                                         java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState
                                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2675)
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1967)
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2321)
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
                                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                                             at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:763)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ea.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:168)
                                                             at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:690)
                                                             at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.da.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:81)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.z.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:66)
                                                             at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$zza$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$3.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zzIL(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.frevo.frevo.diner.fragments.food.DinerFoodMapFragment.onCreateView(DinerFoodMapFragment.java:83)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1984)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:668)
                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:630)
                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2191)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1164)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1157)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1127)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1426)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1536)
                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

My xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.frevo.frevo.diner.fragments.food.DinerFoodMapFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.yarolegovich.discretescrollview.DiscreteScrollView
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_gradient"
        android:id="@+id/discrete_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please, add your xml. The error says, you need the recycler view dependency in your build.gradle

Comment: I have a recycler view but I'm not doing anything with it,  If I remove the recycler view It works. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The error says, you need the recycler view dependency in your build.gradle or remove the recyclerview. Android is trying to inflate your view, but you dont have the dependency.

To use a recyclerview you need an extra dependency is part of support libraries.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
```

More info:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: I guess i need to do something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131256/recyclerview-mapview-crashes-when-rotating-device ..  I will try and I will let you know.